# Comparing two UIColors is not working in the first time

Tags: ios, uialertview

When i click on OK button of an UIAlertView, i need to change the background color of the view, its default color is the white, so every time the user click on OK, i need to alternate between two colors, white and red for example:

```
-(void)changeColor{

        if([self.view.backgroundColor isEqual: [UIColor whiteColor]]){

            self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        }else {
            self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        }
}
```

The problem is that on first OK click, the color is supposed to become red, however it doesn't get the red, so i need to click the OK button the second time to get the view background color with the red. am i missing something to get the color changed from the first time?

This is the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex` delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        //NSLog(@"It's Ok button which has been clicked");
        //Do whatever you want, commonly call to another function like so:
        [self changeColor];
    }else
        if (buttonIndex==1) {
            //NSLog(@"It's Cancel button which has been clicked");
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the background colour of the view is `[UIColor whiteColor]` to begin with?  If it isn't then the first click would make it white and then the second click would make it red.

Comment: Yes, it's configured from IB to the white color, so, it began White

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably isn't the same "white" as returned by `[UIColor whiteColor]`.  If you pick the white color in IB for your view and log it, you get:  `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1`

If you then set the color to `[UIColor whiteColor]`, and log it again, you get: `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1`

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it's not actually [UIColor whiteColor]. Set it manually when the view loads:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```