# Know if textField background color is at it's default color

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicolor

I want to compare if the background color of a `UITextField` is at it's default color.

Something like:

```
if ([blankField.backgroundColor isEqual:nil] 
       && [colorField.backgroundColor isEqual:nil])
{
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942239/comparing-two-uicolors-is-not-working-in-the-first-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to sample a portion of each text field and tell if they are the same as each other. Look at this link:[How does one compare one image to another to see if they are similar by a certain percentage, on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488732/how-does-one-compare-one-image-to-another-to-see-if-they-are-similar-by-a-certai) this link talks about how to compare two images to see if they are similar. Hope this helps.